# Can't close modals after switching if it was already open

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have two modals, one for registration, one for login. Within each modal I have a link to the other modal like this:

Modal Register

```
<span id="btn-open-login"><a id="btn-open-login-link">Back to Login</a></span>
```

Modal Login

```
<span id="btn-open-register"><a id="btn-open-register-link">Register here!</a></span>
```

To close and open the modal without body scroll I use this peace of js:

js

```
$('#btn-open-register').on( 'click', '#btn-open-register-link', function () {
    $("#modalLogin").modal("hide");
    $("#modalLogin").on("hidden.bs.modal",function(){
        $("#modalRegister").modal("show");
    });
});

$('#btn-open-login').on( 'click', '#btn-open-login-link', function () {
    $("#modalRegister").modal("hide");
    $("#modalRegister").on("hidden.bs.modal",function(){
        $("#modalLogin").modal("show");
    });
});
```

The modal Login opens first as default.

It works fine for the first round. But when the Login modal is opened for a second time, I can't close the modal anymore. It just keeps switching.

What am I missing?

Here a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/tk1rbys0/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `modal('toggle')` instead of `"show"` and `"hide"`.

Also, you don't need to listen to the `hidden.bs.modal`. The way you've structured your code, it simply means when you press a modal button, it closes the current modal, when its 'close' event fires, the other modal is shown. You get stuck in a loop, which is your current situation.

Try replacing your code with this:

```
let modalLogin = $('#modalLogin'),
    modalRegister = $('#modalRegister');

$('#btn-open-register').on('click', '#btn-open-register-link', function () {
    modalLogin.modal('toggle');
    modalRegister.modal('toggle');
});

$('#btn-open-login').on('click', '#btn-open-login-link', function () {
    modalRegister.modal('toggle');
    modalLogin.modal('toggle');
});
```

Hope this helps.

Update:

Switch the modals in reversed order, that way you will always have one visible, which will prevent the scrollbar from showing:

```
$('#btn-open-register').on('click', '#btn-open-register-link', function () {
    modalRegister.modal('toggle');
    modalLogin.modal('toggle');
});

$('#btn-open-login').on('click', '#btn-open-login-link', function () {
    modalLogin.modal('toggle');
    modalRegister.modal('toggle');
});
```

**Update 2:**

Taking the scrollbar into account, you can update your code to remove the event listener, once the other modal has been shown.

```
$('#btn-open-register').on( 'click', '#btn-open-register-link', function () {
    $("#modalLogin").modal("hide");
    $("#modalLogin").on("hidden.bs.modal",function(){
        $("#modalRegister").modal("show");
        $("#modalLogin").off("hidden.bs.modal");  // allow closing
    });
});

$('#btn-open-login').on( 'click', '#btn-open-login-link', function () {
    $("#modalRegister").modal("hide");
    $("#modalRegister").on("hidden.bs.modal",function(){
        $("#modalLogin").modal("show");
        $("#modalRegister").off("hidden.bs.modal"); // allow closing
    });
});
```

This should allow you to close an opened modal without showing the other one.

Comment: What sidebar issue are you referring to?

Comment: So, if the site has a scrollbar ... the modal removes the bar when opened and adds it when closed as default. Switching the modals keeps adding and removing the scrollbar, which I don't want. My code prevents this when changing the modal: https://jsfiddle.net/tk1rbys0/ . Your's not: https://jsfiddle.net/zubwhrLc/

Comment: I understand but I don't see the difference between the two examples. I have tried them in Chrome and Safari on Mac and they're identical. What browser are you using on which OS?

Comment: Mozilla Firefox on an ubuntu machine

Comment: Try the following: switch the order in which the modals are toggled. This way, there will always be one visible when switching from login to register and the scrollbar will be visible only when you close the modal completely. I'll update my answer.

Comment: Unfortunately it keeps adding the scrollbar when switching the modals in my browser ... https://jsfiddle.net/zubwhrLc/

Comment: The last fiddle is the first one you posted. The modals are switched in the same order as initially, not like in the updated answer.

Comment: Unfortunately it does not work on my side. This is your first https://jsfiddle.net/zubwhrLc/ suggestion ... and you second: https://jsfiddle.net/o7szqrj5/ . Both show the sidebar when switching the modals ...

Comment: I've updated my answer. Might not be the most elegant solution, though. Since you're using Bootstrap, you can use html attributes to configure modal toggling. Now, if the scrollbars are a critical issue, and you say your solution works, then only the problem of closing the modals remains.

Comment: Thanks. It's working like I hoped. Yet, I only tested it with Firefox. Thanks again. Can delete the first two versions if you want